# How python recursive function works in terms of addition?

Tags: python, function, recursion, addition

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if (k > 0):
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)

        print(result)

    else:
        result = 0
    return result

print("\n\n Recursion Example results ")

tri_recursion(7)
```

The output is adding all numbers by itself till it's length = 7. But I don't know how the function is working.
I mean if k = tri_recursion(7) (7-1 = 6).
Then why first number in output is
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21,

I'm new to programming and this concept of recursive function is not at all clear.
Can anyone explain me how this code is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here?

You originally call the function with k = 7.

1. The function sees that the given value k = 7 is > 0 and thus calculates 7 + the result of the function if called with 6.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 6.
2. The function sees that the given value k = 6 is > 0 and thus calculates 6 + the result of the function if called with 5.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 5.
3. The function sees that the given value k = 5 is > 0 and thus calculates 5 + the result of the function if called with 4.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 4.
4. The function sees that the given value k = 4 is > 0 and thus calculates 4 + the result of the function if called with 3.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 3.
5. The function sees that the given value k = 3 is > 0 and thus calculates 3 + the result of the function if called with 2.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 2.
6. The function sees that the given value k = 2 is > 0 and thus calculates 2 + the result of the function if called with 1.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 1.
7. The function sees that the given value k = 1 is > 0 and thus calculates 1 + the result of the function if called with 0.
   In order to determine the latter, it calls itself with k = 0.
8. The function sees that the given value k = 0 is not > 0 and thus returns 0.

So

- the function run in point 7 calculates 1 + 0 = 1.
- the function run in point 6 calculates 2 + 1 = 3.
- the function run in point 5 calculates 3 + 3 = 6.
- the function run in point 4 calculates 4 + 6 = 10.
- the function run in point 3 calculates 5 + 10 = 15.
- the function run in point 2 calculates 6 + 15 = 21.
- the function run in point 1 calculates 7 + 21 = 28.

In the end, the 28 is returned by the "original function call", but discarded. You see it only because of the `print(result)` inside the function.

There is nothing different to the principle compared to any other recursive function call.

Comment: @blogsbarrel Consider the first call, `tri_recursion(7)`. During the processing of this function call, `k = 7`, so `result = 7 + tri_recursion(6)`. In order to determine what `tri_recursion(6)` is, the function `tri_recursion()` is called with `k = 6`. During that process, `result = 6 + tri_recursion(5)` and so on. Be aware that this `result` variable is different fron that one level above.

Comment: @blogsbarrel This is the "chain" I described with bullet points: during the `tri_recursive(1)` call, it says `result = 1 + tri_recursive(0)`. This evaluates to `1 + 0 = 1`. Then, this call returns to the `tri_recursive(2)` call, where `result = 2 + tri_recursive(1)` then evaluates to `2 + 1 = 3`. Etc.

Comment: Thank you bro, You really helped me I appreciate your efforts